# Why doesn't the for loop save each roll value in each iteration to the histogram?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am creating a for loop to inspect regression to the mean with dice rolls.
Wanted outcome would that histogram shows all the roll values that came on each iteration.

Why doesn't the for loop save each roll value in each iteration to the histogram?

Furthermore PyCharm takes forever to load if n> 20000 values therefore the code doesn't execute fully in that case.

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sums = 0

values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

numbers = [500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 50000, 100000]

n = np.random.choice(numbers)

for i in range(n):

    roll = np.random.choice(values) + np.random.choice(values)
    sums = roll + sums
    h, h2 = np.histogram(sums, range(2, 14))
    plt.bar(h2[:-1], h / n)
    plt.title(n)
plt.show()
```

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYj4v.png)

Comment: np.histogram needs a list/array, and not just a sum

Comment: at each iteration you are overwriting h and h2 with new values. if you want to save each iteration make them a list and append the new results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are now overwriting h and h2 in every iteration. Instead, you could append the values to a list and make a histogram of the entire list:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sums = 0

values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

numbers = [500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 50000, 100000]

n = np.random.choice(numbers)

all_rolls = []

for i in range(n):

    roll = np.random.choice(values) + np.random.choice(values)
    all_rolls.append(roll)
h, h2 = np.histogram(all_rolls, range(2, 14))
plt.bar(h2[:-1], h / n)
plt.title(n)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Histogram]